# How do I call kubectl from CloudFormation?

Tags: kubectl, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I would like to execute kubectl commands using a Cloud-formation. Any idea how do I achieve?

Comment: Could you share more details regarding your use case? How did you setup your cluster? What have you tried already?

Comment: I do not have access to execute any commands on my cluster due to security reasons. Only thing I could do it execute commands like kubectl get nodes via CFN. But I am not sure how to call kubectl using CFN.